# Oracle insert date and convert date

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have a string `"Sat Nov/30/2013"` I have to convert this into date with `dd-MMM-yy format`.

while inserting the date into table I am doing `to_date('Sat Nov/30/2013','dd-MMM-yy')`.

But this is generating `"ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"`

Can you please help me regarding this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DATE` columns do not have any inherent format, they are stored using Oracle's own internal representation. They only have a format for display.

To insert that string into a date column you'd need to use

```
to_date('Sat Nov/30/2013', 'Dy Mon/DD/YYYY')
```

But bear in mind that this is language-sensitive, so the date has to be entered in the same language as the session. You can override that with the optional third parameter to the [`to_date()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions203.htm).

Then to display the date you can use

```
to_char(<field>, 'dd-mon-rr')
```

`MMM` isn't a recognised [datetime format model element](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00212), so I'm guessing you want the month abbreviation. Which is also NLS-sensitive of course.

Comment: @Dba - you're getting ORA-01835? 2014-11-30 is a Sunday, not a Saturday. (Which is where your deleted answer might come in useful, but hopefully the date being passed in is consistent and correct - if not then erroring is probably the right thing to do anyway).

Comment: Yes, You are right. First I've tried with the same way `to_date('Sat Nov/30/2014', 'Dy Mon/DD/YYYY')`, with year 2014. then I got the error `ORA-01835: day of week conflicts with Julian date`. That's why I posted the answer with `substr` funciton. Anyway thanks for your clarification. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
to_date('Sat Nov/30/2013','Dy Mon/DD/YYYY')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use your insert query as below:

```
INSERT INTO DUMMYTABLE (DATE_FIELD_NAME) VALUES (to_date('Sat Nov/30/2013','Dy Mon/DD/YYYY'));
```

Your dummy table should have DATE_FIELD_NAME as "**DATE**" Datatype.